# Bootloader/still learning,

Tags: facebook, security, authentication, boot, public-key-exchange

I was looking at my Facebook message/call log and there's number I don't know, so I was copy and pasting them to look them up, and got the pop up verify it s me question and after I did this code just took over screen. 
I also want to add I unlocked my developer option, and I also think my FB, google, accounts my phone. This is the second time it has happened not sure if same code, I still have the first on.
I have been googling and asking other people, I have learned lots, but darn I still can't figure it all at, just bits and pieces and been working on this for 3 months. I need help and I m loosen my mind..can anyone help?

Here is some of the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Uploading and Managing Your Call Logs</title><meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" /><link href="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/ya/r/O2aKM2iSbOw.png" rel="shortcut icon" sizes="196x196" /><meta name="referrer" content="origin-when-crossorigin" id="meta_referrer" /><meta name="theme-color" content="#3b5998" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" crossorigin="anonymous" data-bootloader-hash="OEPze" href="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yY/l/0,cross/-RGU43oKxbV.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" crossorigin="anonymous" data-bootloader-hash="xILv8" href="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yH/l/0,cross/MLFY5VudT49.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" crossorigin="anonymous" data-bootloader-hash="cFdJm" href="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/y_/l/0,cross/1FUAQskYbo2.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" crossorigin="anonymous" data-bootloader-hash="RoiDK" href="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/y1/l/0,cross/hDC0vMrvPIV.css" /><script id="u_0_q">function envFlush(a){function b(b){for(var c in a)b[c]=a[c]}window.requireLazy?window.requireLazy(["Env"],b):(window.Env=window.Env||{},b(window.Env))}envFlush({"stratcom_event_profiler_hook":"1","timeslice_heartbeat_config":{"pollIntervalMs":33,"idleGapThresholdMs":60,"ignoredTimesliceNames":{"requestAnimationFrame":true,"Event listenHandler mousemove":true,"Event listenHandler mouseover":true,"Event listenHandler mouseout":true,"Event listenHandler scroll":true},"isHeartbeatEnabled":true,"isArtilleryOn":false},"shouldLogCounters":true,"timeslice_categories":{"react_render":true,"reflow":true},"sample_continuation_stacktraces":true,"dom_mutation_flag":true});</script><script>document.domain
= 'facebook.com';/^#~?!(?:\/?[\w\.-])+\/?(?:\?|$)/.test(location.hash)&&location.replace(location.hash.substr(location.hash.indexOf("!")+1));</script><script>__DEV__=0;</script><script id="u_0_r" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3iczx4/yq/l/en_US/IvlINgvLNJi.js" data-bootloader-hash="Yth2c"></script><script id="u_0_o">CavalryLogger=window.CavalryLogger||function(a){this.lid=a,this.transition=!1,this.metric_collected=!1,this.is_detailed_profiler=!1,this.instrumentation_started=!1,this.pagelet_metrics={},this.events={},this.ongoing_watch={},this.values={t_cstart:window._cstart},this.piggy_values={},this.bootloader_metrics={},this.resource_to_pagelet_mapping={},this.initializeInstrumentation&&this.initializeInstrumentation()},CavalryLogger.prototype.setIsDetailedProfiler=function(a){this.is_detailed_profiler=a;return this},CavalryLogger.prototype.setTTIEvent=function(a){this.tti_event=a;return this},CavalryLogger.prototype.setValue=function(a,b,c,d){d=d?this.piggy_values:this.values;(typeof d[a]==="undefined"||c)&&(d[a]=b);return this},CavalryLogger.prototype.getLastTtiValue=function(){return this.lastTtiValue},CavalryLogger.prototype.setTimeStamp=CavalryLogger.prototype.setTimeStamp||function(a,b,c,d){this.mark(a);var e=this.values.t_cstart||this.values.t_start;e=d?e+d:CavalryLogger.now();this.setValue(a,e,b,c);this.tti_event&&a==this.tti_event&&(this.lastTtiValue=e,this.setTimeStamp("t_tti",b));return this},CavalryLogger.prototype.mark=typeof console==="object"&&console.timeStamp?function(a){console.timeStamp(a)}:function(){},CavalryLogger.prototype.addPiggyback=function(a,b){this.piggy_values[a]=b;return this},CavalryLogger.instances={},CavalryLogger.id=0,CavalryLogger.disableArtilleryOnUntilOffLogging=!1,CavalryLogger.getInstance=function(a){typeof a==="undefined"&&(a=CavalryLogger.id);CavalryLogger.instances[a]||(CavalryLogger.instances[a]=new CavalryLogger(a));return CavalryLogger.instances[a]},CavalryLogger.setPageID=function(a){if(CavalryLogger.id===0){var b=CavalryLogger.getInstance();CavalryLogger.instances[a]=b;CavalryLogger.instances[a].lid=a;delete CavalryLogger.instances[0]}CavalryLogger.id=a},CavalryLogger.now=function(){return window.performance&&performance.timing&&performance.timing.navigationStart&&performance.now?performance.now()+performance.timing.navigationStart:new Date().getTime()},CavalryLogger.prototype.measureResources=function(){},CavalryLogger.prototype.profileEarlyResources=function(){},CavalryLogger.getBootloaderMetricsFromAllLoggers=function(){},CavalryLogger.start_js=function(){},CavalryLogger.done_js=function(){};CavalryLogger.getInstance().setTTIEvent("t_domcontent");CavalryLogger.prototype.measureResources=function(a,b){if(!this.log_resources)return;var c="bootload/"+a.name;if(this.bootloader_metrics[c]!==undefined||this.ongoing_watch[c]!==undefined)return;var d=CavalryLogger.now();this.ongoing_watch[c]=d;"start_"+c in this.bootloader_metrics||(this.bootloader_metrics["start_"+c]=d);b&&!("tag_"+c in this.bootloader_metrics)&&(this.bootloader_metrics["tag_"+c]=b);if(a.type==="js"){c="js_exec/"+a.name;this.ongoing_watch[c]=d}},CavalryLogger.prototype.stopWatch=function(a){if(this.ongoing_watch[a]){var b=CavalryLogger.now(),c=b-this.ongoing_watch[a];this.bootloader_metrics[a]=c;var d=this.piggy_values;a.indexOf("bootload")===0&&(d.t_resource_download||(d.t_resource_download=0),d.resources_downloaded||(d.resources_downloaded=0),d.t_resource_download+=c,d.resources_downloaded+=1,d["tag_"+a]=="_EF_"&&(d.t_pagelet_cssload_early_resources=b));delete this.ongoing_watch[a]}return this},CavalryLogger.getBootloaderMetricsFromAllLoggers=function(){var a={};Object.values(window.CavalryLogger.instances).forEach(function(b){b.bootloader_metrics&&Object.assign(a,b.bootloader_metrics)});return a},CavalryLogger.start_js=function(a){for(var b=0;b<a.length;++b)CavalryLogger.getInstance().stopWatch("js_exec/"+a[b])},CavalryLogger.done_js=function(a){for(var b=0;b<a.length;++b)CavalryLogger.getInstance().stopWatch("bootload/"+a[b])},CavalryLogger.prototype.profileEarlyResources=function(a){for(var b=0;b<a.length;b++)this.measureResources({name:a[b][0],type:a[b][1]?"js":""},"_EF_")};CavalryLogger.getInstance().log_resources=true;CavalryLogger.getInstance().setIsDetailedProfiler(true);window.CavalryLogger&&CavalryLogger.getInstance().setTimeStamp("t_start");</script><script id="u_0_p">(function _(a,b,c,d){function e(a){document.cookie=a+"=;expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT;path=/;domain=.facebook.com"}function f(a,b){document.cookie=a+"="+b+";path=/;domain=.facebook.com;secure"}if(!a){e(b);e(c);return}a=null;(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox")!==-1||!window.devicePixelRatio&&navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows Phone")!==-1)&&(document.documentElement!=null&&(a=screen.width/document.documentElement.offsetWidth,a=Math.max(1,Math.floor(a*2)/2)));(!a||a===1)&&navigator.userAgent.indexOf("IEMobile")!==-1&&(a=Math.sqrt(screen.deviceXDPI*screen.deviceYDPI)/96,a=Math.max(1,Math.round(a*2)/2));f(b,(a||window.devicePixelRatio||1).toString());e=window.screen?screen.width:0;b=window.screen?screen.height:0;f(c,e+"x"+b);d&&document.cookie&&window.devicePixelRatio>1&&document.location.reload()})(true, "m_pixel_ratio", "wd", false);</script><meta http-equiv="origin-trial" data-feature="getInstalledRelatedApps" data-expires="2017-12-04" content="AvpndGzuAwLY463N1HvHrsK3WE5yU5g6Fehz7Vl7bomqhPI/nYGOjVg3TI0jq5tQ5dP3kDSd1HXVtKMQyZPRxAAAAABleyJvcmlnaW4iOiJodHRwczovL2ZhY2Vib29rLmNvbTo0NDMiLCJmZWF0dXJlIjoiSW5zdGFsbGVkQXBwIiwiZXhwaXJ5IjoxNTEyNDI3NDA0LCJpc1N1YmRvbWFpbiI6dHJ1ZX0=" /><link rel="manifest" href="/data/manifest/" crossorigin="use-credentials" /></head><body tabindex="0" class="touch x2 android _fzu _50-3 iframe _2v9s"><script id="u_0_n">(function(a){a.__updateOrientation=function(){var b=!!a.orientation&&a.orientation!==180,c=document.body;c&&(c.className=c.className.replace(/(^|\s)(landscape|portrait)(\s|$)/g," ")+" "+(b?"landscape":"portrait"));return b}})(window);</script><div id="viewport" data-kaios-focus-transparent="1"><h1 style="display:block;height:0;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;width:0;padding:0">Facebook</h1><div id="page" class=""><div class="_129_" id="header-notices"></div><div class="_129- _6dr5"><div class="_52z5 _451a _3qet _17gp" id="header" data-sigil="MTopBlueBarHeader"><div class="_4g33 _52we" id="mJewelNav"><div class="_4g34"><div class="_59te jewel _hzb noCount" data-store="&#123;&quot;tab&quot;:&quot;feed&quot;,&quot;tabID&quot;:4748854339&#125;" id="feed_jewel" data-sigil="nav-popover feed"><a name="News Feed" accesskey="1" href="/home.php" class="_19no touchable" id="u_0_7" data-sigil="icon"><span style="display:block;height:0;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;width:0;padding:0">News Feed</span><div class="_2ftp _62ta"><div class="_59tf _2ftq"><span class="_59tg" data-sigil="count">0</span></div></div></a></div></div><div class="_4g34"><div class="_59te jewel _hzb noCount" data-store="&#123;&quot;tab&quot;:&quot;requests&quot;,&quot;tabID&quot;:122818001061574&#125;" id="requests_jewel" data-sigil="nav-popover requests"><a href="/friends/center/requests/?rfj" name="Friend Requests" accesskey="2" class="_19no touchable" data-store="&#123;&quot;behavior&quot;:&quot;custom&quot;&#125;" id="u_0_8" data-sigil="icon"><span style="display:block;height:0;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;width:0;padding:0">FRIEND REQUESTS</span><div class="_2ftp _62ta"><div class="_59tf _2ftq"><span class="_59tg" data-sigil="count">0</span></div></div></a><div class="flyout popover_hidden" role="complementary" id="reqs_flyout" data-sigil="flyout flyout"><div data-sigil="flyout-content context-layer-root"><div id="MFriendRequestsFlyoutContent"><ol class="_7k7 inner" data-sigil="contents requests-flyout-pagelet-placeholder"><li class="acw apl" data-sigil="marea"><div style="text-align:center;"><div class="_2so
_2sq _2ss img _50cg" data-animtype="1" id="u_0_4" data-sigil="m-loading-indicator-animate m-loading-indicator-root"></div></div></li></ol></div></div><div class="_imu"></div></div></div></div><div class="_4g34"><div class="_59te jewel _hzb noCount" data-store="&#123;&quot;tab&quot;:&quot;messages&quot
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what your question is? I don’t understand what you did or where or how this relates to programming or bootloaders

Comment: I am learning how to  programming, and coding and I'm still new, and I have had these codes pop up on my phone while on FB. I m trying to understand them, and do as much reading, and research but I am still lost. If this isn't the right place to look for help, sorry.. thought someone here could help me understand these codes. l can keep searching.

Comment: Still no clue what you are even asking about.